# How to add a part of layout dynamicaly when user press a button in android?

Tags: android

when fragmnet called first time

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dizrM.png

when user clicked + (plus) button

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TntNX.png

and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Use `Inflater` to add part of Layout in parent Layout.
Follow this link :
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html